# Excel Floating Point Arihmetic - What Type Does It Actually Use

Tags: excel

From a previous questions someone indicated that Excel uses a 64 bit (8 byte) double-precision floating.

Is that correct - Is there any material on this at all?

I am trying to tie off numbers and this is killing me!

Answer (score 5):

According to this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113) yes, it uses 64 bit double precision floating point numbers. The article also describes the rounding errors etc associated with this format.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at

[Floating-point arithmetic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113)

Under the section **Precision**

> A floating-point number is stored in
>   binary in three parts within a 65-bit
>   range: the sign, the exponent, and the
>   mantissa.

Here is another article

[Understanding Floating Point Precision, aka “Why does Excel Give Me Seemingly Wrong Answers?”](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers.aspx)

Have a look at the section **Structure of a Floating Point Number**