# Excel VBA odd maths result

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem with some logic statements in a Case Select. However, I've tracked it down to some odd maths by excel. The following formula is evaluating as True in the immediate window when I would expect it to be false

```
?(0.09 /0.1)<0.9
```

Can anyone explain why this would be?

Comment: why is there a `?` before your function? (never seen it)

Comment: @t.thielemans: `?` is the `print` statement. @Michael: read up on binary floating-point numbers on a computer. This is a rounding issue.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/rounding.htm here (floating point section) is a good link to talk about floating point rounding.  If you use ? round((0.09/0.1),1)<0.9  the result is correct

Comment: ?followed by a statement in the immediate window will give you an instant result. I use it to test any formula that I'm having issues with.

Comment: stephan/scott - Thanks for the info, I've converted my variables from doubles to currency, and it is evaluating as expected now. I'll need to find time to read up on rounding later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Floating point arithmetic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113) may give inaccurate results in Excel.

For a more in-depth article, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245017/excel-floating-point-arihmetic-what-type-does-it-actually-use) right here on StackOverflow.

@scott has the solution in his comment:

```
? round((0.09/0.1),1)<0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because vb converts the expression to integer which resolves to zero. Try

```
   ?  CDBL((0.09/0.1) < 0.9
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. Still resolving to True.